# Match generated balls with the same number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I created a program that:

- generates 4 balls on the screen with a number inside them
- then the user types in the values he wants to give to new circles to be generated.

On clicking on a button, the new 4 circles with a number inside them get generated under the already generated balls.

If the ball numbers in the 2nd line match the ones in the first, then the ball should be displayed under that particular ball.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="one0" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
  <input id="one1" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
  <input id="one2" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
  <input id="one3" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
  <input id="result" value="click here" type="button" style="width:70px;" onclick="go()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <script>
      var arr=[];
      var x=[];
      var y;
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
      arr[i]=5*(i+1);
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = 0;
      var centerY = 90;
      var radius = 70;
      var temp;
      var xar=[];
        for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        centerX=centerX+100;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle="black";
      context.fillText(arr[i],centerX,centerY);
      }

        function go(){
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
          temp=parseInt(document.getElementById("one"+i).value);
          xar.push(temp);
        }
      console.log(xar);
      var xnext=0;
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
      xnext=xnext+100;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(xnext, 190, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle="black";
      context.fillText(xar[i],xnext,190);
      if(xar[i]==arr[i]){
       context.arc(xnext, 190, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      }


      }

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The button will generate the balls but doesn't do the number matching.

**NOTE** jsfiddle isn't showing the result properly. It isn't showing any result on clicking the button.
https://jsfiddle.net/59p5k15q/

Answer (score 0):

I moved the if() to the start of function go(), to just before you start drawing on the canvas.
(I kept xnext+=100 to make sure the x-value is correct.)

It seems to work fine now.  My second set of balls are red.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="one0" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="one1" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="one2" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="one3" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="result" value="click here" type="button" style="width:70px;" onclick="go()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
  var arr=[];
  var x=[];
  var y;
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    arr[i]= 5 * (i+1);
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = 0;
  var centerY = 90;
  var radius = 70;
  var temp;
  var xar=[];
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    centerX=centerX+100;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle="black";
    context.fillText(arr[i],centerX,centerY);
  }
  function go() {
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
      temp = parseInt(document.getElementById("one"+i).value);
      xar.push(temp);
    }
    console.log(xar);
    var xnext=0;
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
      xnext=xnext+100;
      if(xar[i] == arr[i]) {
        continue;
      }
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(xnext, 190, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#330000';
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle="black";
      context.fillText(xar[i],xnext,190);
      context.arc(xnext, 190, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    }
  }
</script>
```